# PLS-00428: se espera una cláusula INTO en esta sentencia SELECT al crear procedimiento en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy creando un procedimiento sencillo, en SQL, simplemente su funcionamiento se basa en devolver los datos de aquellas incidencias que se encuentran en situación=2 y no han llegado a la situación=3, junto con el nombre del usuario reportador y el tipo de usuario.

El problema es que al compilar me salta esta advertencia:

> Error(4,3): PLS-00428: se espera una cláusula INTO en esta sentencia SELECT

¿Cómo puedo cambiar mi código para que sea correcto?

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE incidenciasDatos2 IS
BEGIN
  SELECT i.id_reportador, i.id_tipo, s.* FROM incidencia i, situacion s 
  WHERE i.id_incidencia = s.id_incidencia AND s.id_estado = 2 AND s.id_estado <> 3;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, te falta introducir el resultado en una variable, aquí necesitas usar la cláusula **INTO**.

Te modifico la consulta para que te quede bien y te paso una referencia para que lo entiendas https://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedure-select-into-example/:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE incidenciasDatos2 IS
     BEGIN
variable varchar(200);--lo que sea

     SELECT i.id_reportador, i.id_tipo, s.* INTO variable
    FROM incidencia i, situacion s    
    WHERE i.id_incidencia = s.id_incidencia AND s.id_estado = 2 AND s.id_estado <> 3; 
    END;
```

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)

Answer (score 0):

debería salir con un cursor.

Por ejemplo

```
 PROCEDURE incidenciasDatos2 ( p_sal           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR   )
```

y en el `begin`

```
OPEN p_sal FOR
SELECT i.id_reportador, i.id_tipo
    FROM incidencia i, situacion s    
    WHERE i.id_incidencia = s.id_incidencia AND s.id_estado = 2 AND s.id_estado <> 3; 
end;
```

es un poco tarde, tal vez ya hiciste la corrección, pero puede que les sirva a las personas que aun tengan ese problema.